# Android Studio - Can't run Blank Activity on actual device (LogCat keeps the Logs coming and nothing show up on the device)

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat, lg

So i opened a new `Blank Activity` and tried to run it on my `LG G3` `API 5.0`.

And `Android Studio` keeps Logging messages (Infinite messages[They never stop]) but the application is never opened in the actual device.

So the `LogCat` shows my device settings...

Again, The `LogCat` is infinite.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: can you share some of the logcat when launching your application?

Comment: @ClaytonWilkinson I shared before and edited. It's really weird. Non stop Logs :(. Anyways here the better question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091654/my-app-just-building-and-never-installs-apk-on-actual-deviceandroid-studio.

Answer (score 0):

The logs that are being shown are for your device without a filter. So it is showing all the logs from your phone, NOT from your application or blank activity. If you want the logs just for your application change the settings for logcat in android studio (top right of Android Monitor window) to "Show only selected application and in the top left select your application or application package name. Then you should only get logs from that class/application.

Comment: And what about the thing that the app isn't running? And to change the settings i enter `Android Device Monitor`? and then what?

Comment: after entering android device monitor you should see a couple of drop down boxes. 1 for device, another for package/application and another for filter (No Filter, show only selected applications, etc). 

As for the activity not being launched I would make sure that the activity is declared in your manifest for you application.