# My app just building and never installs apk on actual device(Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

So after running the app i get this `Gradle Console` and the `apk` is never installed on my device thus the app is never shown.

**Gradle Console:**

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.534 secs
```

**Manifes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.search.lyrics.limbo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Maybe the problem is with my manifest?
It's just a new Android project with a `Blank Activity`. I did nothing to the code except for adding the `intent filter` tag in the manifest.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**
I get this line when I'm trying to run:
`Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found`

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: try to launch it on the emulator.

Comment: @RomanRozenshtein The emulator is not working as well.

Comment: do you click the "play" button to run the project?

Comment: What if you look in the Run window in the bottom left corner. Do you see the adb commands in there to start the app on the device?

Comment: @RomanRozenshtein Yes.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan I get this on the there `Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found`

Comment: post your Activity class code

Comment: @RomanRozenshtein Posted  it.

Comment: please post it including all the file (imports, package name etc..)

Comment: @RomanRozenshtein Found an answer. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action name is case sensitive so you need to update `Main` to `MAIN` like below in your `intent-filter`.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me often, and I don't have a good way to fix it every time.

I have gotten into the habit of deleting the `/app/build` and `/build` folders, as well as the `/gradle` folder. I think this is usually the same as running a `gradle clean`

If that didn't work, I get more aggressive, close Android Studio, delete `.idea/` folder and delete any `*.iml` files. Run gradle build to make sure it passes, then re-open Android Studio, and let it import the gradle project.

Comment: Too  messy for me HAHA.

Comment: This is the only method I found to be reliable. I think the project intermediate files become stale, and the only way to refresh them is to take a big hammer and smash it.